# How to apply search in Elasticsearch in python with and without whitespces

Tags: python, csv, elasticsearch

I am building a search system using ElasticSearch in python. I loaded a csv and created an index for search.

```
from elasticsearch import helpers, Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch()

with open('/Users/anubhav/Office/elasticsearch-5.6.0/all_products.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='product-index', doc_type='product-index')

es.indices.create(
    index='product-index',
    body={
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
              "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
            }
          },
          "tokenizer": {
            "my_tokenizer": {
              "type": "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram": 2,
              "max_gram": 10,
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit",
                "whitespace"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    # Will ignore 400 errors, remove to ensure you're prompted
    ignore=400
)

response = es.search(
index='product-index',
body={
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "product": "PD5MP2 price"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "top_10_states": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "state",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
)

print response
```

The csv looks something like:
[image: CSV sample]

when I do search using:

```
res = es.search(index="product-index", doc_type="product-index", body={"query": {"match": {"product": "DD 350"}}})
```

this works fine because the exact product is there in CSV. But when I change the query to

```
res = es.search(index="product-index", doc_type="product-index", body={"query": {"match": {"product": "DD350"}}})
```

It doesn't works. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

By default Elasticsearch uses [Standant Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) which divides text into terms on word boundaries, as defined by the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm. That means `DD 350` will be tokenized as `DD, 350`. When you search, search keywords also will be tokenized as same tokenizer. So when you search for `DD 350` Elasticsearch will look for both `DD` and `350` and both is in your index. But when you search for `DD350` Elasticsearch won't be able to find it index. You should check the [tokenizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html) and their usage.

Comment: I have updated the question with current code I am using. But when I remove the "ignore 400" line in settings, it gives me an error saying "index already exist". Can you please also suggest me the tokenizer for this?